# Python memory limit? Clear GC when close to limit?

Tags: python, windows, eclipse, memory, garbage-collection

How would I clear garbage collected objects before performing other memory intensive operations? Or is it done automatically when the memory is full?

Why does it seem that Python (+Eclipse) throws a Memory Exception at 2 GB (Win32) whereas actually still some memory is unused on Windows? Are there limits defined anywhere?

Comment: Is such high memory usage to be expected or is it a memory leak? In the latter case, no GC can help, you'll have to find and fix the leak yourself.

Comment: In that case it is expected, however I will think about some advanced features where I don't load all data at once, but store some lengthy bits on the harddrive being referenced only.

Answer (score 4):

You can tweak the performance of the garbage collector with the `gc` module -- for example, with [`gc.set_threshold`](http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html#gc.set_threshold) -- or you can "manually" collect the garbage: [`gc.collect`](http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html#gc.collect). However, I believe that most of the time, objects are collected as soon as their refcount goes to zero.

So to be explicit about it, (thanks delnan!) garbage collection is only an issue when there are cyclic references that keep refcounts from reaching zero.

Note also this line from the `gc` docs:

> To debug a leaking program call `gc.set_debug(gc.DEBUG_LEAK)`.

Comment: Note that what CPython calls its garbage collector is just a GC for cyclic references. All objects not in cycles will be taken care of by refcounting as soon as they become unreachable. That assumes of course they do become unreachable and you aren't holding onto references you don't need any more.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 32bit Application have a limit of 2GB maximum memory. There a is a boot option that will bump it to [3Gb](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124810%28EXCHG.65%29.aspx). You can also try upgrading to 64bit Windows/Python.

Comment: Upgrading probably means another processor? :) I have it at home, but at work computers are old and the budget limited...